# simple stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I created a following stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @Surname nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @Password nvarchar(255);

SELECT TOP 1 FirstName, Surname, Email, Password FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @PersonID;
```

In this case, I want to set the result into the four variables. How to do this, I don't know. Please, help me someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOte that your `Select` itself, has 4 column why you have to put them in other variable? it not a good job. By the way for each field you can use

```
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(255); 
DECLARE @Surname nvarchar(255); 
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(255); 
DECLARE @Password nvarchar(255);  
SELECT TOP 1 @FirstName = FirstName, @Surname = Surname, @Email = Email, @Password = Password FROM Person WHERE PersonID = @PersonID;
```

I Strongly Recommend Don't use this approach